# Are Ruby regular expressions Perl or POSIX-compatible?

Tags: ruby, regex

Are Ruby regular expressions PCREs and/or POSIX-compatible basic/extended regexes?

Comment: Please see [The Stack Overflow regular expressions reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)!

Comment: Neither - ruby uses Onigmo

Comment: Much closer to Perl than POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

> Are Ruby regular expressions PCREs and/or POSIX basic/extended regexes?

No, they are Ruby [`Regexp`s](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html).